# In Vue 3.* how to pass ref object itself into an event handler with template syntax?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

```js
<script setup>
 import { ref } from 'vue'

 const foo = ref(1)
 
 function changeSth(sth, val) {
   sth.val = val;
   // an error trigger, because ref object is unwrapped, sth is just a plain value
 }

</script>

<template>
<button @click="changeSth(foo, 2)">click me change sth.</button>
</template>
```

I wanna pass ref object `foo` into function `changeSth`。 so that I can reuse `changeSth` to do something like `changeSth(foo) changeSth(bar)`. But now I can only get the value of ref object. So, how to pass ref object itself into event handler like `changeSth` with template syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
 <button @click="changeSth(ref(foo), 2)">click me change sth.</button>
   {{ foo }}
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const foo = ref(1)

 const changeSth = (sth, val) => {
    sth.value = val
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Somehow this worked, although a helper function like `preventUnref` would be nice for use cases like these. I had to use `computed(foo)` though, instead of `ref(foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like following:

```
<template>
 <button @click="changeSth('foo', 2)">click me change sth.</button>
   {{ foo }}
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const foo = ref(1)

  function changeSth(sth, val) {
    this[sth] = val
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried, but not work. this in changSth scope is undefined

Comment: @wxttt hey mate, I tested it and it's working, did you pass value as string `@click="changeSth('foo', 2)"`

Comment: Hi, thank u for your help. Maybe there is something wrong with my environment. In function `function changeSth(sth, val) { this[sth] = val}`,the this is `undefined`. So this code not work.My vue version is 3.2.26 I will try to update the version.